# How to Remove named range from workbook with their corresponding cells using microsoft graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to delete the named range with its data cells using the following API
`POST /workbook/names/{name}/range/delete` Although its delete the data associate with named range but not remove the name of range from workbook. the named range was still there with`"value": "#REF!"`. so is there any graph API which can remove this name of range with data?

Comment: Try using `DELETE /workbook/names/{nameditem name}`

Comment: Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity thanks i tried this and it remove the name of the range from workbook but it not remove the name range data. although i was looking for single API but i can use the combination of this APIs, so thanks.

Comment: Glad to here it resolves your issue. Yes you can use both the calls to delete the whole thing. Moving this to Answer.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below two calls one after the other.

```
POST /workbook/names/{name}/range/delete

DELETE /workbook/names/{nameditem name}
```

This deletes the whole data and the metadata of the nameditem.